# Save a .sql file vs Create a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

In the last days I started to read a lot of documentation about SQL Server and I "found" the concept of Views.

I already know them, but only because they are used during discussions about SQL Server.

So, if anyone can help me, this is what I understand about views:

1) The view is physically saved in the database

2) You can give only the access of a view to a person without giving them access to the entire database

3) You can write a new query and use the join clause with the view

This three points are the difference that I understand from a normal .sql file, saved on disk.

But, other than this three difference, why should I create a view instead of save a query if I don't have problems with the database access?

I really don't understand why a lot of people talk about views, especially for SQL Server reports and I want to improve my knowledge.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because a view behaves like a table in the DB and anyone with the DB login can query it, whereas a SQL file  on your disk is a query only you can run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view is a *stored query*; it doesn't contain any data. For example, if you *export* it from the database (talking about Oracle here), you'll see that you exported 0 rows.

As such, it is available to you and any other user who has access to it. If query - used to create a view - is stored on your hard disk, how am I supposed to use it (unless you send it to me, to Scott and Mick and Jenny and ...) and then someone changes their view and we won't fetch the same data set, although we all started from the same point.

A view can restrict data access; you can allow other people fetch only a small column set from a table. Or, if you join 7 tables to create a view and grant `select` privilege on it to someone else, they have *no idea* what lies behind as they see data only.

I don't, though, have an impression that *a lot of people talk about views*; maybe you think so as you're reading about them now. But, no doubt that they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can work with view like a table.if you have a view called viewTest,for example.
you can select from it(select * from viewTest),join it , .... .
it is very different from saves file.